# Drag row into empty table using Dragula

Tags: javascript, dragula

I'm trying to use Dragula (with angular-dragula actually) to drag a row from one table to another. If both tables have rows there are no problems, but there are cases where the target table will be empty. How do I make the empty table allow for a drop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the table is too small? Try changing `min-height`.

---

Insert a placeholder row when there is nothing in the table
http://plnkr.co/edit/0TBXXZOBAKnGxHig3xzD?p=preview

Comment: I have tried to modify the min-height but it doesn't seem to register for a table with no rows..

Comment: inserting a placeholder row solved this for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by using the power of angular2. If the array (models) is empty I add a div as the dragula container, else I display that container holding the array. where class drop bag has "min-height:50px";

```
    <div *ngIf="models.length > 0">
        <div
        *ngFor="let model of models" 
        [dragula]='"third-bag"'
        [dragulaModel]='models'
        class="dropbag">
            <div class="col-xs-12 center-content">
                <img [src]="model.imageThumb" alt="NA">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="models.length <= 0">
        <div
        [dragula]='"third-bag"'
        [dragulaModel]='models'
        class="dropbag">
            <div class="col-xs-12 center-content">
                <img src="" alt="No Content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```